# Quartz triggers not being saved to the mysql database

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to save the quartz scheduler jobs to the database so that it can sustain server crash. And can start automatically on server start up. The problem is that I managed to save the job in the database but I can't see the trigger.

Any idea on this issue? I am using quartz 2.2.1 SimpleTrigger and also tried CronTrigger but no luck. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you post your configuration file (quartz.properties is the default)? It's not clear, you can see in your DB jobs but not triggers?

Comment: I'm having the same issue, only jobDetails table is filed, rest all is empty. Did you figured out ?

Comment: Yep, you have to override the quartz.properties file. and put it in your classpath that was the only problem. Also you have to create tables or configure to fire the scripts http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.x/configuration/ this link will help .. :) :) I am also posting the quartz.properties for reference in answer (as I can't paste it here ;) ).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is just for the information of others asked for it in comment so posting my configuration for future reference of others, for me it was just configuration issue, I created the database tables manually. following is the configuration.

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = quartzScheduler
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.StdJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = qrtz_
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = quartzDataSource
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.scheduler.skipUpdateCheck=true


# Following is to be changed according to database.
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.driver = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.URL=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.user = root
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.password = root
# This should be equal to or more than the number of thread configured below.
org.quartz.dataSource.quartzDataSource.maxConnections = 30 

#org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = false


org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 30
org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true



org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class = org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerFiredMessage = Trigger {1}.{0} fired job {6}.{5} at: {4, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerCompleteMessage = Trigger {1}.{0} completed firing job {6}.{5} at {4, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.triggerMisfiredMessage = Trigger {1}.{0} misfired job {6}.{5} at: {4, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}. Should have fired at: {3, date, HH:mm:ss MM/dd/yyyy}
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.class = org.quartz.plugins.management.ShutdownHookPlugin 
org.quartz.plugin.shutdownhook.cleanShutdown = true

# It's plugin that chaeck the configuration file every 10 seconds and updates the database accordingly.
# NOT NEEDED
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class=org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames=quartz-scheduler.xml
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound=true
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval= 10
#org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction=false
```

This was stored under the name of quartz.properties and was in classpath for quartz to find.